# link_to a form in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to use the link to function to point to a form.
i.e <%= link_to 'Reports', '/reports/index.html.erb' %>
But this gives me a error saying no route matches '/reports/index.html.erb.

Thanks,
Ramya.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails doesn't like having the document format in the URL unless it's necessary (like when one action can handle multiple request formats). If you have `reports/index.html.erb`, the route to it would look like one of these:

```
match 'reports' => 'reports#index' #=> 'yourdomain.com/reports'
match 'reports/index' => 'reports#index' #=> 'yourdomain.com/reports/index
```

Then your link would be:

```
<%= link_to 'Reports', 'reports' %>
```

or

```
<%= link_to 'Reports', 'reports/index' %>
```

If you really wanted to have the `.html`, you could probably do it like this:

```
match 'reports/index.html' => 'reports#index' #=> 'yourdomain.com/reports/index.html
```

or

```
match 'reports/index.:format' => 'reports#index' #=> 'yourdomain.com/reports/index.html
```

But the `.html` is meaningless in the first case and unnecessary in the second. I don't recommend doing it this way, as it's not standard Rails practice.

I *highly* recommend you read [this tutorial on Routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html), at least the first few sections, before you move forward. It's an absolutely essential part of Rails, and if you don't understand how it works, you will never be a productive Rails programmer.

Comment: Hi bricker,I don't have a class for reports. so please let me know the format to use the report in routes.erb

Comment: Well you have to have a controller for the routes to route to. Where is the form in your application?

Comment: the form is in /app/view/reports. the thing is reports are generated from the existing models.There is no table called reports exists.Its just pulled from different tables. So is there a way to have a set of forms without a model or a controller

Comment: You don't need a model, but you have to have a controller. Routes works directly with the controller to serve the views to the client. Without a controller, routes has nowhere to go. Just make a routes controller and put an index action in it, `rails g controller reports index`. That'll even create the route for you.

Answer (score 2):

The link should point to the form from the server's point of view. Try `<%= link_to 'Reports', '/reports/index.html' %>` *(without the '.erb')*

Make sure that your routes really define that url. I guess it may be '/reports/' instead of '/reports/index.html', but YMMV.

Consult the output of command `rake routes` to see what routes are defined.

Comment: Hi,I tried its giving the error No route matches "/reports/index.html".Do ineed to define it the routes.erb.If so please help with the format

Comment: Try '/reports/'. I guess you may have something like `resources :reports` in your 'config/routes.rb' file. If not, you may try to add it there. In case of problems, post your 'config/routes.rb' file and we will help.

Comment: Bricker's suggestion of reading the routing tutorial is good. I also highly advocate doing so.